# Easy csv to excel

Tags: excel, vba, csv, ms-access

My customer has an issue with certain .csv files auto detecting data types and altering data when they open in excel. Current workaround is to open an instance of excel, open the file, and go through the many-step process of choosing data types.

There is no standard format for which data elements will be in each csv file, so I've been thinking up methods to write code that is fairly flexible. To keep this short, basically, I think I've got a good idea of how to make something flexible to support the customer's needs that involves running an append query in Access to dynamically alter/create specifications, but I cannot figure out how to obtain values for the "Start" and "Width" fields in the MSysIMEXColumns table.

Is there a function in vba that can help me read a csv file, and gather the column names along with the "Start" and "Width" values? Bonus if you can also help me plug those values into an Access table. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: As @abraxascarab notes, you shouldn't need start and width if your files are really CSV.  If they're really fixed-width then it would help to post a couple of examples of the kind of thing you're dealing with.

Comment: It's definitely csv. I'll put together some screenshots on Monday to show the issue.

Comment: You guys were right -- don't NEED start and width. without them, however, it defaults to applying column settings alphabetically which messes up the data unless your csv file happens to be organized with the columns ascending alphabetically.

If you sort on the START field in the MSysIMEXColumns, and run an append query to put ascending values in the START field based on column order, then it solves the issue. So now, I've got a button to pull in a csv (any csv) and output an xlsx. User inputs are required if they want a field NOT pulled in as short text, but it's a one-time input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all... there is **NO** "easy csv to Excel" conversion when your customer has:

"...no standard format for which data elements will be in each csv file."

I used to work for a data processor where we combined thousands of different customer files, trying to plunger them into a structured database.  The ways customers can mangle data are endless.  And just when you think you've figured them out, they find news ways of mangling data.

I once had one customer who had the brilliant idea of storing their "Dead Beat" flag **IN** their Full name field.  And then didn't tell us they did so.  And then when we mailed the list out to their customers, they tried to blame us for not catching that.  Can you imagine someone waking up some morning and get junk mail addressed to "Dear, Dead Beat"?

But that's only one way "no standard format" customers can make it impossible to catch their errors.  They can be notorious for mixing in text with number fields.  They can be notorious for including invisible escape characters in text fields that make printers crash.  And don't even get started on how many different ways abbreviations can cause data to be inconsistent.

Anyway... to answer your question:
If you are using CSV files, they are comma delimited.  You don't need "Start" and "Width".

"Start" and "Width" are for Fixed Width files.  And if your customer is giving you a fixed width file,  they NEED to give you a "standard format".  If they don't then you are just trying to mind read what they did.  And while you can probably guess correctly most of the time, inevitably, you are going to guess wrong and your customer is going to try to blame you for the error.

Other than that, sometimes you just have to go through the long slog of having a human visually inspect things to make sure the convert went as planned.  I'd also suggest lots of counts and groupings on your data afterwards to make sure they didn't do something unexpected.

Trying to convert undocumented files is a very difficult and time consuming task.  It's why they are paying you big bucks to do it.

So to answer your question again, "Start" and "Width" are for Fixed Width files.  If they are sending you Fixed Width files, they need to send specifications.

If it's a csv file, you don't need "Start" and "Width".  The delimiter (ususally a comma) is what separates your fields.

** **EDIT** **

Ok... thinking through this some more... I'll take a guess at what you are doing:

1) You create and save a generic spec in Access for delimited files.

2) You open your CSV file through vba and read the new delimited header record with all the column header names.

3) You try to modify the MSysIMEXColumns table to include new fields and modify old ones.

4) You now run your import based on the new spec you created.

If that is the case, you need to do a couple of things:

First, understand that this a dangerous thing to do.  Access uses wizards to create it's systems tables.  If you muck with these, you don't know how it might affect the wizards when they try to access these tables again.  You are best off creating a new spec for each new file type, using the Access wizards.

Second, once you come to the conclusion you are smarter than microsoft (which is probably a good bet anyway), you can try to make a dynamic spec file.

Third, you NEED to make sure your spec record in MSysIMEXSpecs is correct.  That means you need to have it set as a delimited file and have the correct delimiter in there. Plus you need to have the FileType correct.  You need to know if it's Unicode or any number of other file types that your customer could be sending you.

And by "correct delimiter" I mean... try to get your customer to send you "pipe delimited" `|` files.  If they send you "comma delimited" files, you run the risk of them sending you text fields with comments or addresses that include a comma in the data.  Say they cut and paste a street address that has a comma in it... that has the fantastic effect of splitting that address into two fields and pushing ALL of your subsequent columns off by one.  It's lots of work to figure out if your data is corrupted this way. Pipes are much less likely to be populated in your data by accident.

Fourth, assuming your MSysIMEXSpecs is correct, you can then modify your MSysIMEXColumns table.  You will need to extract your column headers from your csv file.  You'll need to know how many fields there are and their order.  You can then modify your current records to have the new field names and add any new records for new fields, or delete records if there are less fields than before.

I'd suggest saving them all as text fields `DataType=10` in a staging table.  That way you can go back and do analysis on each field to see if they mixed text into numeric fields or any other kind of craziness that customers love to do.

And since you know your spec in MSysIMEXSpecs is a delimited field file, you can give each record a "Start" field equal to the sequence your Header record calls for.

```
Attributes  DataType    FieldName   IndexType   SkipColumn  SpecID  Start   Width
0           10          Rule        0           0           3       1       1
0           10          From Bin    0           0           3       2       1
0           10          toBin       0           0           3       3       1
0           10          zone        0           0           3       4       1
0           10          binType     0           0           3       5       1
0           10          Warehouse   0           0           3       6       1
0           10          comment     0           0           3       7       1
```

Thus, the first field will have a "Start" of 1.  The second field will have a "Start" of 2.  etc.

Then your "Width" fields will all have a length of 1.  Since your file is a delimited file, Access will figure out the correct width when it does the import.

And as long as your SpecID is pointing to the correct delimited spec, you should be able to import any csv file.

Fifth, after the data is in your staging table, you should then do an analysis of each field to make sure you know what type of data you really have and that your suspected data type doesn't violate any data type rules.  At that point you can transfer them to a second staging table where you convert to the correct data types.  You can do this all through VBA.  You'll probably need to create quite a few home grown functions to validate your data.  (This is the **NOT** so easy part about "easy csv to Excel" coding.)

Sixth, after you are done all of your data massaging, you can now transfer the good data to your live database or Excel spreadsheet.  Inevitably you'll always have some records that don't fit the rules and you'll have to have someone eyeball the data and figure out what to do with it.

You are at the very tip of the iceberg in data conversion management.  You will soon learn about all kinds of amazingly horrible stuff.  And it can take years to write automated procedures that catch all the craziness that data processors / customers send to you.  There are a gazillion data mediums that they can send the data to you in.  There are a gazillion different data types the data can be represented in.  Along with a a gazillion different formats that the data resides in.  And that's all before you even get to think about data integrity.

You'll probably become very acquainted with GIGO (Garbage In, Garbage Out).  If your customer tries to slip a new format past you (and they will) without telling you the "standard format for which data elements will be", you will be left trying to guess what the data is.  And if it's garbage... best of luck trying to create an automated system for that.

Anyway, I hope the MSysIMEXColumns info helps.  And if they ever give you Fixed Length files, just know you'll have to write a whole new system to get those into your database.

Best of luck :)

Comment: So, did an import on a random csv file, set specs, and saved them. To test how import would behave without "Start" and "Width", I deleted the values in those fields, then did an import using that spec on the same file. None of the fields ended up in the same place. I understand your logic, but I think the spec uses those values to determine which field to apply which name, data type, attributes, etc, (?)

Comment: You can idiot-proof your application to the nth degree but then the n+1 idiot will come along.  Users will provide a bigger (better?) idiot than you can ever predict.

Comment: Gahhh... don't delete the values in the "Start" and "Width" fields.  You are mucking around with system files.  Just leave them as they are after you created the initial Spec file.  Even if the "Width" is not big enough for future files you import, it doesn't matter.  Access will still adjust and import the correct field width.  (As long as you have it set to be a delimited file that is.)

Comment: Hmmm... I'm trying wrap my brain around what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to create your own spec by altering/adding a record to the system table MSysIMEXSpecs?

Comment: Hey... I added more info to my Answer above.  It explains "Start" and "Width" in the context of delimited files where you are trying to modify the system tables for the spec.  Just remember, it's dangerous to modify the system tables since Access wizards are trying to use them in mysterious ways.  Sometimes you can guess right... other times... it does things you never dreamed of.  Proceed at your own risk... in yonder coding, there be dragons.

Comment: I think you and I got to pretty much the same result. Here's what I ended up doing:

1) There are 5 tables in play. First are the two system tables for the spec. Made a generic spec for column delimited which remains untouched. MSysIMEXColumns table is emptied before/after every conversion. Temp_Conversion table is where the imported file is placed. Temp_Defs is where the column names, order, and types are put. (continued in next comment)

Comment: Ref_Defs is the reference where the user stores column names and types that might be messed up during conversion (ie. Serial Number keeps dropping the leading zeroes because access thinks it's a number. You can make an entry in Ref_Def so all fields called 'Serial Number' in any imported csv file are imported as short text). 

2) Menu with two buttons, first button launches a File Explorer window so the user can pick the CSV file. Access holds on to the file path.

3) If the file is not a 'csv' file, the next button ends with a message box. If it is a 'csv' file, the following will occur:

Comment: Drop Temp_Conversion table. Clear Temp_Defs. Clear MSysIMEXColumns. Import the csv based on the file path with no spec applied. Run a loop on the table pulling out the fields' names, order, and types. Insert looped values into Temp_Defs. Query using values from Temp_Defs compared to fields/types in Ref_Defs -- APPEND to MSysIMEXColumns as spec. DROP Temp_Conversion table. Import csv again using the new spec. Export as excel using TransferSpreadsheet. Drop all ImportError tables. Drop Temp_Conversion again. Message box "Complete!".

Comment: Awesome... it sounds like you have the beginnings of a great system. :)